# Android XMPP battery life

Tags: android, xmpp

I tried googling this quite a bit, but all the articles are from early 09 where things were much different. Seeing currently hardware and stuff, whats the battery life like when using XMPP on Android as a service?

Edit:
I am currently using the ASmack library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That question depends on your implementation: The Google XMPP CLient Talk, for instance uses PUSH notification, with long open TCP connections, hence battery consumption is relative low. Other implementations might use different techniques, hence you should check that.

Comment: What about If I am using the ASmack XMPP library which is based on Smack?

Comment: can't tell never used this one. But if you like you could apply some modification to make it suitable for C2DM (Cloud to Device Messaging) available on Android 2.2 .

Comment: I was wondering why google talk client was using less battery than most other XMPP clients :)